# again problem with java date

Tags: java, date

I want to know the number of days of date, the getDay() method returns wrong answer, how can 
i know the correct number of days ?

Comment: Huh? Number of days of date? Please explain.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Number of days since what? The start of the year? The UNIX epoch? The thriller music video?

Comment: You need to clarify your question

Comment: @Chris - thriller video, definitely

Comment: the number of the days of month

Comment: @Vahan You mean the number of days _in_ the month? E.g., May has 31 days?

Comment: @ Isaac Truett  i wanted to know which is day of the month, all that i needed is getDate() method

Comment: Modern approach: `java.time.LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really explore the [java.util.Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) API

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class for that. Here is an example:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

There is a [`getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29) method on the [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class but it's been deprecated because it didn't correctly handle some edge cases.

The method you tried to use ([`java.util.Date.getDay()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29)) actually returns the day of the week, not the day of the month. In any case, it's been deprecated too similar to above.

If you don't like the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class's clunky interface, you could give [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) a try.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the day of the month? check this http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate()

**Edit:**

This is only if you're using Date (not recommended since most of all methods are Deprecated). If you're willing to use Calendar (which is far better and not full of Deprecated methods) you can do things such as:

```
int dayOfTheMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Date` is really only kept around for quick date to integer conversions, for any actual math related to dates, you need to use a subclass of `java.util.Calendar` which can figure out things like how many hours there are in a day (which isn't constant if you remember daylight savings time, etc.), how many days in a month (again not constant), etc.

Since you are probably working with Gregorian calendars (the 12 month, January, February, etc. calendar), you probably want to use java.util.GregorianCalendar.  There are other calendars available, even if they might not all be shipped with the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the one the docs say not to use?

```
 int getDay() 
      Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK).
```

Use the `Calendar` classes.